Movie about special forces or mercenaries in Brazil
I am looking for a movie I saw a long time ago about a special forces team or mercenaries set in Brazil. The movie was in Portuguese and everyone was Brazilian. They all turn on one of their own because he disagrees with their next mission.
Notable scenes include:

A raid on an outpost and they blow up one guy in a hallway filled with grenades (that they set up there).
A scene where the (good) guy hides a boy in the fridge to save him from a gas explosion set up to kill him (the man).
The final scene is in an airport/large public transport station with lots of smokebombs and a final stand off between the main guy and the rest of the team

It all happens in an urban setting. I think the movie starts on an empty/disused runway.

Could you elaborate how long "a long time ago" is approximately?

Could be Elite Squad

@FranzXaver - that is a good movie but it's not that one

Was the movie original language English? Were the mercenaries brazilian or the team was just in Brazil?

@Luciano the movie was in Portugese and everyone was Brazilian

Can't you remember any of the actors? that would narrow down immensely

The movie is The Expendables; the movie was filmed at Brazil; specifically in Parque Julano, Rio de Janeiro, Mangaratiba, Niteroia and Guanabara Bay. 
But the question is mixing two movies: The Expendables 1 and The Expendables 2; the first part you ask is when Barney, the "chief", wants to return to Milena (a fictional country) where a girl from the Resistance awaits for him; the entire group tell him the mission is a suicidal thing. The scene referred in the final is the second part of Expendables, where Barney, Hull and Church met before they return to US.

Hm, he wrote "long time ago". Expandables is from 2010. So this was either a very bad hint (which could be possible, and then you are right) or he means another movie

I used the data he provided and this movie, so far, is the one who approach to the script. Of course, he could provide more data to unestimate this.

@nelruk That is not the movie - it was older than that - i suspect it is a movie from the early nineties. Interesting though ... perhaps Expendables copied this movie in some way. I can see why you would think it is that movie

OP says the movie was in Portuguese, so that would exclude any of The Expendables for sure
